# eks fluent-bit to elasticsearch timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-eks, fluent-bit

So I had a working configuration with fluent-bit on eks and elasticsearch on AWS that was pointing on the AWS elasticsearch service but for cost saving purpose, we deleted that elasticsearch and created an instance with a solo elasticsearch, enough for dev purpose. And the aws service doesn't manage well with only one instance.

The issue is that during this migration the fluent-bit seems to have broken, and I get lots of "[warn] failed to flush chunk" and some "[error] [upstream] connection #55 to ES-SERVER:9200 timed out after 10 seconds".

My current configuration:

```
[FILTER]
    Name                kubernetes
    Match               kube.*
    Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
    Kube_CA_File        /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    Kube_Token_File     /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
    Kube_Tag_Prefix     kube.var.log.containers.
    Merge_Log           On
    Merge_Log_Key       log_processed
    K8S-Logging.Parser  On
    K8S-Logging.Exclude Off
[INPUT]
    Name              tail
    Tag               kube.*
    Path              /var/log/containers/*.log
    Parser            docker
    DB                /var/log/flb_kube.db
    Mem_Buf_Limit     50MB
    Skip_Long_Lines   On
    Refresh_Interval  10
    Ignore_Older      1m
```

I think the issue is in one of those configuration, if I comment the kubernetes filter I don't have the errors anymore but I'm loosing the fields in the indices...

I tried tweeking some parameters in fluent-bit to no avail, if anyone has a suggestion?

So, the previous logs did not indicate anything, but I finaly found something when activating trace_error in the elasticsearch output:

```
{"index":{"_index":"fluent-bit-2021.04.16","_type":"_doc","_id":"Xkxy     23gBidvuDr8mzw8W","status":400,"error":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reas     on":"object mapping for [kubernetes.labels.app] tried to parse field [app] as o     bject, but found a concrete value"}}
```

Did someone get that error before and knows how to solve it?

Comment: The most common reason i've seen for "failed to flush chunk" is that the batch upload queue on the ES cluster is full. You're sending more data than the cluster can index. Enabling debug logging in fluentbit should give more info.

Comment: In that case why can I get the data when I remove the filter?

Comment: Ah, then it could be a mapping conflict. definitely enable debug logging

Comment: I added debug logs in the question if it helps.

Comment: The strange thing is that it works one or 2 times when the pods are created and then I get the flush chunk.

Comment: I found the error when I activated the trace_error from the es output, I updated the post again.

Comment: yeah, mapping conflict. that means you have two different things outputting different data types for the "app" key.

Comment: Yep, I just don't get how it can cause that issue on a field like a label..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after looking into the logs and finding the mapping issue I ssem to have resolved the issue. The logs are now corretly parsed and send to the elasticsearch.

To resolve it I had to augment the limit of output retry and add the Replace_Dots option.

```
[OUTPUT]
    Name            es
    Match           *
    Host            ELASTICSERVER
    Port            9200
    Index           <fluent-bit-{now/d}>
    Retry_Limit     20
    Replace_Dots    On
```

It seems that at the beginning I had issues with the content being sent, because of that the error seemed to have continued after the changed until a new index was created making me think that the error was still not resolved.